# SharePoint user/group role concept issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am programming with SharePoint Service 3.0/SharePoint Server 2007. SharePoint has some built-in roles like contributor, visitor, designer, administrator.

I am wondering if I use Forms Authentication, how to define roles in Forms Authentication Roles in order to map the Forms Authentication roles to SharePoint built-in roles?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic mapping from FBA roles to SharePoint groups (just like there is no automatic mapping from AD groups)

So you're free to call your FBA roles anything you want. You'll then usally assign some FBA user Full Control using Central Admin (You need to add the FBA <membership><provider> entry to CAs web.config). And use this account to sign into the FBA site and add the roles to the SharePoint groups.

Comment: Thanks Per, 1. I want to confirm two points, FBA you mean form based authentication? 2. For SharePoint you mean there is no role concept, only group concept? 3. "You need to add the FBA <membership><provider> entry to CAs web.config" -- any easy way to do from Administration GUI?

Comment: 1: Yes, FBA = Form Based Authentication.
2: Yes, in SharePoint it's called Groups, they are then mapped to Permission Levels
3: No, There is no UI for the web.config.
If you haven't already then it might be a good idea to look at the MSDN article about FBA: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975136.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The roles you define in  Forms Authentication are comparable to Acitive Directory Security Groups, these can then in turn be made a member of sharepoint groups, just like with Active Directory groups.

Comment: Thanks! "these can then in turn be made a member of sharepoint groups, just like with Active Directory groups." -- still a little bit confused. Could you explain in more details if I create a role called Administrator and I want to map all members in Administrator role to be administrator of SharePoint, what are the steps in SharePoint Central Administration?